# When should I use a webcontrol and when should I use a UserControl?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, .net-4.0, web-controls

It seems UserControls apart from the benefit of being able to place controls in a markup doesn't really have any other advantages over WebControl.

In fact, they have several disadvantages. Such as
- Cannot use across multiple projects by putting into assembly
- Difficulty in passing objects in Constructor

My question is, why should I use a UserControl over a WebControl and vice versa?

Is it just a matter of taste? Or are there any hidden pros and cons that I don't know about.

Comment: [Documentation is your friend](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893667).  Towards the bottom there's a nice chart that summarizes both, you pick whichever one suits your particular situation best.

Comment: @R0MANARMY : Thanks that is useful, you should put that inside an answer so you get points for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ServerControl versus UserControl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314831/servercontrol-versus-usercontrol)

Comment: It's a fairly basic question and is often used as an interview question.  I would have been shocked if it wasn't asked before (it just took a few tries to find a similar one) and not answered by people much smarter than I am =).

Comment: @R0MANARMY, +1 for the great link